# Extending the function in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let's take a function $f:\Bbb R^k \supset A \rightarrow \Bbb R^m$, such that: $(1): \forall_{x,y\in A}:|f(x)-f(y)| \le |x-y|$. Is it true that every such function can be extended to function $f':\Bbb R^k \rightarrow \Bbb R^m$ (it means $f'_{|A}=f$) which preserves the property $(1)$ ? (As it can be observed we consider the $\Bbb R^n$ spaces witch euclidean metric.)

Answer (score 1):

At least for $m=1$, the answer is yes, and the construction is both quite clever and quite standard:
$$f'(x)=\sup_{a\in A}\big(f(a)-\lvert x-a\rvert\big).$$
Think of it this way: Take the solid cone $$\{(y,t)\colon \lvert y-x\rvert\le t-c\}$$ and push it down (i.e., making $c$ as small as you can) until it intersects the graph of $f$. The resulting value of $c$ is $f'(x)$.

**Update:** In Evans and Gariepy: *Measure theory and fine properties of functions* one can find an extension theorem of this type on page 80. However, the Lipschitz constant of the extension can grow by a factor $\sqrt{m}$. But the authors also state that *Kirszbraun's theorem* gives the bound you are after. Their reference is Federer: *Geometric Measure Theory*, Section 2.10.43. But you can also find the result [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirszbraun_theorem).

Comment: Is it perhaps connected to some bigger theory, because it seems hard for me to come up with such construction ? Can I read somewhere about similar problems ?

Comment: @J.E.M.S: I don't know if stackexchange notifies you of updates to anwers to your question, so here is a heads up that I did edit my answer.

Comment: It is very helpful, thanks.